# How to create a Status Bar popover view (menu)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

[image]

The triangle at the top looks so wonderful, but I can't compose one like that.

I had tried to write some code as below, but I saw an ordinary menu.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {// Insert code here to initialize your application

NSStatusItem * statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:110] retain];
[statusItem setTitle:@"Test"];
[statusItem setEnabled:YES];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

statusItem.menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"menu"];
NSMenuItem * menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"menuItem1" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
[statusItem.menu addItem:menuItem]; }
```

[image]

Please help me to do something to carry it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [`NSPopover`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you, omz! I've done according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
// Insert code here to initialize your application

NSStatusItem * statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:110] retain];
[statusItem setTitle:@"Test"];
[statusItem setEnabled:YES];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setTarget:self];
[statusItem setAction:@selector(showPopover:)];
}

- (void) showPopover:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"sender is: %@", sender);
RSTestPopoverViewController * viewController = [[RSTestPopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RSTestPopoverViewController" bundle:nil];
NSPopover * popover = [NSPopover new];
popover.contentViewController = viewController;
[popover showRelativeToRect:NSZeroRect ofView:(NSView *)sender preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
}
```

The parameter of popover callback is an instance of NSStatusBarButton class.
Here is the output in my console.

```
2013-01-20 23:08:36.602 TestMacWindow[1190:303] sender is: <NSStatusBarButton: 0x101917d10>
```

Comment: What if i want to show popover programmatically? [[nsapp delegate] showPopoover:???]; what should i pass as parameter/sender. how can i get nsstatusitem barbutton